# MySQL.. Return '1' if a COUNT returns anything greater than 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create MySQL query that essentially returns true or false.  I'd like to run

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
  FROM comments  
 WHERE comment_date >= 1306904400 
   AND user_id = 1
```

So if the user posted in the forum 10 times this month, I'd like it to return just 1, otherwise I'd like it to return 0 to indicate they haven't.

Is that possible efficiently within SQL?

Answer (score 32):

If you don't mind MySQL-specific things then you could use [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
select if(count(id) >= 10, 1, 0)
from comments
where comment_date >= 130690440
  and user_id = 1
```

Or [MySQL booleans](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html#id864561) (which are 1 for true and 0 for false):

```
select count(id) >= 10
from comments
where comment_date >= 130690440
  and user_id = 1
```

If you want to stick to standard SQL, then [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) is your friend:

```
select case when count(id) >= 10 then 1 else 0 end
from comments
where comment_date >= 130690440
  and user_id = 1
```

Comment: select case when count(id) >= 10 then 1 else 0 end

this command helps me so much, thank you

Answer (score 16):

Use `CASE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS `flag`
FROM `comments`
WHERE `comment_date` >= 1306904400 AND `user_id` = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to count all the matching records, just find if one exists.  Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't appear to support `IF EXISTS` as Microsoft SQL Server does.  However, you can use a subselect with `LIMIT` to fake it:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS has_comments FROM (SELECT id FROM comments WHERE comment_date >= 1306904400 AND user_id = 1 LIMIT 0, 1) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but here's another way to accomplish this:

`SELECT COUNT(id), 1 % (1 + count(id)) as greaterThanZero
  FROM comments

 WHERE comment_date >= 1306904400 
   AND user_id = 1`

Answer (score 0):

perhaps:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM comments  
WHERE comment_date >= 1306904400 AND user_id = 1) > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a LIMIT to do something similar, and just evaluate it in my code. The SQL will stop after finding 10 matches.

```
SELECT id FROM {mytable}
WHERE comment_date >= 1306904400
AND user_id = 1
LIMIT 10
```

PHP requesting a minimum of 10 posts.

```
if(my_db_query() != 10)
    not_enough_posts();
```