# MySQL: Add Default Value to Joined Table when Row not Found

Tags: mysql, join

System info:

```
$ uname -srvm
Linux 5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 x86_64

$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

I am very inexperienced with MySQL & have been looking for an answer to this for about half a week. I am working with two tables named `character_stats` & `halloffame` that I want to join in a query. They look like this:

```
mysql> SELECT name, level FROM character_stats;
+-----------+-------+
| name      | level |
+-----------+-------+
| foo       |     0 |
| bar       |     0 |
| baz       |     3 |
| tester    |     4 |
| testertoo |     2 |
+-----------+-------+

mysql> SELECT * from halloffame;
+----+-----------+----------+--------+
| id | charname  | fametype | points |
+----+-----------+----------+--------+
|  1 | bar       | T        |      0 |
|  2 | foo       | T        |      0 |
|  3 | baz       | T        |      0 |
|  4 | tester    | T        |      0 |
|  5 | testertoo | T        |      0 |
|  6 | tester    | D        |     40 |
|  7 | tester    | M        |     92 |
|  8 | bar       | M        |     63 |
+----+-----------+----------+--------+
```

In my query, I want to display all the rows from `character_stats` & I want to join the `points` column from `halloffame` for `fametype='M'`. If there is no row for `fametype='M'`, I want to set `points` to `0` for that character name, instead of omitting the entire row as is done in the following:

```
mysql> SELECT name, level, points FROM character_stats JOIN
    -> (SELECT charname, points FROM halloffame WHERE fametype='M')
    -> AS hof ON (hof.charname=name);
+--------+-------+--------+
| name   | level | points |
+--------+-------+--------+
| tester |     4 |     92 |
| bar    |     0 |     63 |
+--------+-------+--------+
```

So I want it to output this:

```
+-----------+-------+--------+
| name      | level | points |
+-----------+-------+--------+
| foo       |     0 |      0 |
| bar       |     0 |     63 |
| baz       |     3 |      0 |
| tester    |     4 |     92 |
| testertoo |     2 |      0 |
+-----------+-------+--------+
```

I have tried to learn how to use `IFNULL`, `IF-THEN-ELSE`, `CASE`, `COALESCE`, & `COUNT` statements from what I have found in documentation & answers on stackoverflow.com. But as I said, I am very inexperienced & don't know how to implement them.

The following works on its own:

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT points FROM halloffame WHERE fametype='M'
AND charname='foo' LIMIT 1), 0) as points;
```

But I don't know how to join it to the `character_stats` table. The following would work if I knew how to get the value of `character_stats.name` before `COALESCE` is called:

```
SELECT name, level, 'M' AS fametype, points FROM character_stats
JOIN (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT points FROM halloffame WHERE
fametype='M' AND charname=name LIMIT 1), 0) AS points) AS hof;
```

According to [Adding Default Values on Joining Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553412/adding-default-values-on-joining-tables) I should be able to use `CROSS JOIN`, but I am doing something wrong as it still results in `Unknown column 'cc.name' in 'where clause'`:

```
SELECT name, level, points FROM character_stats
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM character_stats) AS cc
JOIN (SELECT COALESCE((SELECT points FROM halloffame WHERE
fametype='M' AND charname=cc.name LIMIT 1), 0) AS points) AS hof;
```

Some references I have looked at:

- [Returning a value even if no result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449899/returning-a-value-even-if-no-result)
- [Usage of MySQL's "IF EXISTS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528854/usage-of-mysqls-if-exists)
- [Return Default value if no row found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558295/return-default-value-if-no-row-found)
- [MySQL.. Return '1' if a COUNT returns anything greater than 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234561/mysql-return-1-if-a-count-returns-anything-greater-than-0)
- [How do write IF ELSE statement in a MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763310/how-do-write-if-else-statement-in-a-mysql-query)
- [Simple check for SELECT query empty result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884996/simple-check-for-select-query-empty-result)
- [Is there a function equivalent to the Oracle's NVL in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239498/is-there-a-function-equivalent-to-the-oracles-nvl-in-mysql)
- [MySQL: COALESCE within JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912132/mysql-coalesce-within-join)
- [Unknown Column In Where Clause With Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917849/unknown-column-in-where-clause-with-join)
- [Adding Default Values on Joining Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553412/adding-default-values-on-joining-tables)
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/returning-a-value-even-if-there-is-no-result-in-a-mysql-query

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can do the following:

```
SELECT name, level, COALESCE((SELECT points FROM
halloffame WHERE fametype='M' AND charname=name
LIMIT 1), 0) AS points FROM character_stats;
```

Though I would still like to know how to do it within a `JOIN` statement.